# Passing Server Name into T-SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure that is being called by an app from different environments (DEV/QA). From the stored procedure below, I wanted to pass the server name as a parameter, replacing "HARDCODEDSERVER" with the one passed as parameter "@Server"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MySTOREDPROCEDURE
   @Id Int,
   @Server nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @TempTable Table (
 -- Declarations
 )

 DECLARE @TempTable2 Table (
 -- Declarations 
 )

 INSERT INTO @TempTable
  SELECT a.* FROM Table a
   Inner Join [HARDCODEDSERVER].[DatabaseName].dbo.[TABLE1]
   -- And so ON

 INSERT INTO @TempTable2
  SELECT b.* FROM Table b
   Inner Join [HARDCODEDSERVER].[DatabaseName].dbo.[TABLE1]
   -- And so ON

 BEGIN TRANSACTION
 BEGIN
    UPDATE @TempTable  -- rest of the process for TempTable
    UPDATE @TempTable2  -- rest of the process for TempTable2
    -- The rest of the SP
 END
 COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

I have used the dynamic SQL approach, but this doesn't work since it cannot scope @TempTable even previously defined already:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(2000);

SET @SQL = '
 INSERT INTO @TempTable
  SELECT a.* FROM Table a
   Inner Join [ ' + @Server + '].[DatabaseName].dbo.[TABLE1]
   -- And so on
'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Tried the same for EXEC but same issue where it can't find @TempTable:

```
EXEC ( '
 INSERT INTO @TempTable
  SELECT a.* FROM Table a
   Inner Join [ '' + @Server + ''].[DatabaseName].dbo.[TABLE1]
   -- And so on
')
```

I have checked other answers here in SO but most only works on single operations. Any help where the server name can be parameterized and still be able to work/scope on the Temp Tables?

Comment: If you convert the table variables to temp tables then you will be able to access them in the scope of a dynamic sql call. Or, if you want to keep them as table variables, then you'll have to pass them as parameters in a call to sp_executesql.  In SQL Server Lower scopes have access to temp tables created in the scope of a higher level caller.

Comment: Asides: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`. Don't use the `sp_` prefix for stored procedures as explained [here](https://sqlnuggets.com/do-not-prefix-stored-procedures-with-sp_/).

Comment: Also things like servername should be typed as *sysname*; Using temp tables would be the preferable and easier option.

Comment: @squillman - I have used instead temp tables and you are correct. The EXEC() function now sees the tables and I was able to pass the correct server name in the queries!

Comment: @Patrick Good deal, glad it's working for you now!

Comment: Or you could just put the whole thing including the table variables inside dynamic SQL

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use temp tables (created using `CREATE TABLE #tablename`) as these are visible to any procedures or dynamic SQL called from the same connection.

---

Another option is to create this procedure on the remote server itself. Then you can call it like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MySTOREDPROCEDURE
   @Id Int,
   @Server sysname
AS

DECLARE @procName nvarchar(1035) = @Server + '.[Databasename].[dbo].[sp_MySTOREDPROCEDURE]';

EXEC @procName @Id = @Id;

go
```

---

Alternatively, just place the whole procedure into dynamic SQL, rather than just the `INSERT` statement

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MySTOREDPROCEDURE
   @Id Int,
   @Server sysname
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '

 DECLARE @TempTable Table (
 -- Declarations
 );

 DECLARE @TempTable2 Table (
 -- Declarations 
 );

 INSERT INTO @TempTable
  SELECT a.* FROM Table a
   Inner Join ' + QUOTENAME(@Server) + '.[DatabaseName].dbo.[TABLE1];
   -- And so ON

 INSERT INTO @TempTable2
  SELECT b.* FROM Table b
   Inner Join ' + QUOTENAME(@Server) + '.[DatabaseName].dbo.[TABLE1];
   -- And so ON

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE @TempTable  -- rest of the process for TempTable
    UPDATE @TempTable2  -- rest of the process for TempTable2
    -- The rest of the SP

 COMMIT TRANSACTION;
';

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@Id int',   --  declare parameters on this line
  @Id = @Id;    --  pass all parameters like this

go
```

Note the following:

- Use of `QUOTENAME` to quote the server name
- Store the server name in a `sysname` variable, which is the same as `@nvarchar(128)`
- Store dynamic SQL in `nvarchar(max)`
- Pass through parameters properly